# Make a zip() pandas columns to sum up other columns with unique index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, zip, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns:

- store
- product
- price

For each store we have multiple products, but each product has a unique price.
The DataFrame is hence composed of multiple rows on the same store, each row corresponding to a product.

I would like to make some transformations on the dataset to get only one line per store, and a compound column that would sum up info about products and prices as follow:

> `[(product_1,price_1),(product_2,price_2), ...]`

For now I've not been able to do it.

What I have done is that I've grouped by `store`, aggregated by product, and applied the `.unique()` function. I get for each store, a list of all the products, but not the prices. When I try to add `price` to the `.agg()` function followed by `.unique()` it doesn't work and have no clue how to do this.

I guess I might have to apply some zipping at some point: `zip(product, price)` but I don't get until there.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby("store", as_index = False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'store': x["store"].iloc[0],
                                                                "result": [(val["product"], val["price"]) for idx, val in x.iterrows()]}))
```